# How a block work in a C++ program

Tags: c++, output, block

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int i=10;
int main()
{
  int i=20;
  cout<<i<<" "<<::i;
   {
     int i=30;           //from here
     cout<<endl<<i<<" "<<::i;
    }
  cout<<endl<<i<<" "<<::i<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
20 10
30 10
20 10
```

Here I am unable to understand the last value of 'i' in the output, why it is 20 not 30.

Kindly see the comment **from here**, there if I replace **int i=30;** with **i=30;**.

Now the output is:

```
20 10
30 10
30 10
```

Why here the last output value of 'i' is changed with respect to the above code.

**Finally the most important question that what is the application of using blocks?**

Comment: Because the `i` in `i=30` only exists in the block scope.

Comment: @juanchopanza But Sir when I am removing 'int' in the block scope then the output is different.

Comment: Because then you are accessing the `i` from the enclosing scope.

Comment: its correct output. when you change `int i = 30` to  ´i = 30`, actually middle `i` is replaced with 30 which was previously 20.

Comment: What is the application of blocking? And how one can use blocking in a program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have three different variables called `i` in this program:

- A global one,
- A local one in `main`, and
- Another local one within a block in `main`.

Within the block, when you refer to `i`, you get the local variable defined within that block.  Outside the block — including after it — the variable in the block isn't visible, so when you refer to `i` you get the one defined in `main` itself.  And in all cases, `::i` refers to the global variable.

When you change `int i=30` to `i=30` in the block, you're no longer creating a new variable within the block; instead, you're modifying the `i` variable that was defined at the top of `main`, which is the same one that's seen by the output statement after the end of the block.

Answer (score 4):

That is exactly how scoping works. The `i` in the inner most block is a completely different `i` than the one outside the block, it just happens to have the same name. This introduces [name shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

If you intend to use the original variable, don't declare it as `int` again, or you are defining a new variable. If your intention is to use a new variable, pick a different name for it.

Answer (score 3):

```
{
     int i=30;           //from here
     cout<<endl<<i<<" "<<::i;
}
```

You are creating a local variable i which is equal to 30. The local variable i has block scope. This overrides the variable i outside. Once it is outside of the braces, the local variable i is deleted or it is out of scope.

When it is changed,

```
{
     i=30;           //from here
     cout<<endl<<i<<" "<<::i;
}
```

It is referring to the same variable.. So no new local variable creation. You are just assigning i = 30.

Whereas `::i` refers to the global variable i which has file scope, is declared at the top.